# Register IDbContext in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, dbcontext

I'm trying to register IDbContext in Unity but I'm getting this 
error

> "The type IDbContext does not have an accessible constructor."

**UnityConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IProductServices, ProductServices>();
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));

    //---all ERROR below---
    //container.RegisterType(typeof(IDbContext), typeof(DbContext));
    //container.RegisterType<IDbContext>(); 

    var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationContext"].ConnectionString; 

    container.RegisterType(typeof(IDbContext), typeof(DbContext), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(connectionString));

}
```

**IDbContext.cs**

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity;

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

**ApplicationContext.cs**

```
public partial class ApplicationContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext()
        : this("name=ApplicationContext")
    {
    }
    public ApplicationContext(string name)
        : base(name)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

Comment: does DbContext have a public constructor?

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't use `IDbSet<T>` I found it didn't have `AddRange` and `RemoveRange` method signatures on it, which are really useful. I would just stick to `DbSet<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 constructor in your `DbContext` therefore Unity can not initialize it simply remove `ApplicationContext(string name)` constructor an let default exist.

```
public partial class ApplicationContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
     public ApplicationContext()
         : this("name=ApplicationContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

An in unity side write:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, ApplicationContext>();
```

But if you want keep your constructors try this:

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, ApplicationContext>(
    new InjectionConstructor("YourConnectionStringYouProvidedSomewhere"));
```

Comment: if I remove ApplicationContext(string name) I get design time error "'ProjectName.ApplicationContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Comment: if I add container.RegisterType<IDbContext, ApplicationContext>(); then I get run time error "Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

Answer (score 1):

So you could do something like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("connectionstringproperty") { }
}

public interface IMyContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{

}

public class MyContextFactory : IMyContextFactory
{
    public MyContext Create() 
    {
        return new MyContext();
    }
}
```

Register Like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyContextFactory, MyContextFactory>(new PerResolveLifetime());
```

And use in class like so:

```
public class UserService
{
    IMyContextFactory contextFactory

    public UserService(IMyContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public List<User> GetUsers() 
    {
         using(var context = this.contextFactory.Create())
         {
              return context.Users.ToList();
         }
    }
}
```

I don't use repositories until I really have to (which is nearly never :) ). But if `UserService` was a repository class instead (it kinda is at the moment) the implementation would be the same using constructor injection.

### DbContext

If you want testability, EF 6 did a good job in making all methods and properties virtual so you could override them rather than creating an interface to back it.

For dependency injection, EF created `IDbContextFactory<T> where T : DbContext`

You should be inheriting from `DbContext` so that you can create some tables in the database. When you inherit you can create different constructors depending on your needs, the easiest I find is to create a parameterless one and call the base constructor overload which takes the `web.config` connection string property.

Answer (score 1):

`DbContext` does not have a public, default constructor. The most minimial public constructor is one which takes a string value containing the name of the connection string to use (defined in your `app.config` or `web.config` file) or the actual connection string to the database itself.

If you have such a connection string defined in your `app.config` or `web.config` (or you have a suitable default connection string to be used throughout your application), try the following Unity registration:

```
// In the code below, "connection_string" is either the full database
// connection string or the name of the connection string as defined
// in the app.config or web.config files
//
// NOTE: This method requires a LifetimeManager. 
// I used the default "singleton container" provided by unity.
// This may not be appropriate for your application--please use an
// appropriate container lifetime manager.
container.RegisterType(typeof(IDbContext), typeof(DbContext),
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionConstructor("connection_string"));
```

If you have multiple databases you will need to connect to, then you may want to subclass `DbContext` (e.g. `MyDB1DbContext`, `MyDB2DbContext`) or use *named registrations*. If you subclass `DbContext`, then you could have the subclasses implement a public default constructor, passing a suitable connection string to the base `DbContext` class--at which point, your context registrations become simpler.

For one application-wide `DbContext` though, I'd probably just use the code snippet above.

### Update after OP's Update

Unless you'll need to use multiple connection strings with your application-defined `DbContext`, I would simply define as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext() : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("my_connection_string_name")
    { }

    ... // Rest of context class definition
}
```

Then, to register:

```
// NOTE: Can also use the generic version--may need to also change the
// lifetime management of the context depending on your application.
container.Register(typeof(IDbContext), typeof(ApplicationDbContext), 
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: i'm getting this error "'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer' does not contain a definition for 'RegisterType' and the best extension method overload 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType<T>(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, string, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.LifetimeManager, params Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Hmm, see my amended answer. Apparently, you can't use the generic version of this method.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight you were just missing a lifetime from the previous example, you didnt have to change it completely

Comment: I edited my post just to provide more info...also I'm getting new error "The type System.Data.Entity.DbContext cannot be assigned to variables of type ProjectName.Data.IDbContext.
Parameter name: from"

Comment: If you created you own `IDbContext` interface, there's really no need to. In fact, you don't need to inherit from both `System.Data.Entity.IDbContext` _and_ `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`--just `DbContext`. If that `IDbContext` is your own, I would remove that (or, if you "extended" the interface, then call it something else like `IMyOwnDbContext`--which inherits from the base `System.Data.Entity.IDbContext`--to prevent naming collisions).